# mesh generating server/client side?

Tags: 3d, client, send, mesh

For a particular project, I have two options:
-send info about how to generate meshes via the internet to clients which then have to generate them all themselves
or
-generate meshes server-side and transmit the entire meshes via the internet to all the clients

Which would be more efficient in the long run or at least more practical?
I think the program I'm mimicking actually generates them server-side but I'm worried about trying to send that much data.

Comment: typically, if you want your site to scale to many visitors, you need to offload as much as possible to the clients. of course, if it's a one-off calculation, you can do it on the server and store the result and send it. but if the result is too large and computation is cheap, do it on the client.

Answer (score 0):

they really do send instructions to their clients, rather than the actual meshes. I will do the same.